# How to create an algorithm to initialise variables?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I don't know exactly how to describe my question but I want to make this code shorter. Instead of creating each brick separately, how would I go about creating an algorithm that created bricks for me? (using a for loop or something?)

Here is the part of my code:

```
    bricks[1] = new GameObject(20, 90, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE);
    bricks[2] = new GameObject(60, 90, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE);
    bricks[3] = new GameObject(100, 90, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE);
    bricks[4] = new GameObject(140, 90, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE);
    bricks[5] = new GameObject(180, 90, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE);
    bricks[6] = new GameObject(220, 90, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE);
```

So the first two values could be represented like so:
x = 20;
y = 90;

x should be increment by *40* each time
y should only increment by 60 when x is 540

x should reset back to *20* after y is incremented

42 Maximum bricks

How would I write this?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: You can use nested `while` loops - `while y<max_y{ while x<max_x{ makeBrick(x,y); incrementX();} x=0; incrementY(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throw the code in a loop and increment your (x?) value:

```
int xCounter = 20;
int yCounter = 90;
for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
    // Increment y
    if (x == 540) {
        yCounter += 60;
        xCounter = 0;
    }

    bricks[i] = new GameObject(xCounter, yCounter, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE);

    // Increment x
    xCounter += 20;
}
```

EDIT: Updated the logic; didn't see the extra requirements. The trick here is to check when x equals 540 and increment the y counter and reset the x counter accordingly.

Note that we're using the current index of the loop (variable 'i') to populate the array dynamically as we iterate 42 times (bricks[i] = ...).

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = 20, y = 90;
for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
    bricks[i] = new GameObject(x, y, BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, Colour.BLUE);
    x += 20;
    if ( x >= 540 ) {
        y += 60;
        x = 0;
    }
}
```